# K8S - how to separate Pod definition from StatefulSet definition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

In the example below, the Pod definition is embedded in the StatefulSet definition. Is there a way to separate the Pod definition to refer to a separately defined Pod definition?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "separate"?

Comment: You could indirectly do this using templating tools like Helm, but not in Kubernetes directly -- the StatefulSet controller itself takes responsibility for creating the Pod, and the Pod template is always inline in the StatefulSet specification.  Is there a specific reason you want this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to separate the Pod definition to refer to a separately defined Pod definition

**No.**

For longer version, here is [definition of StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#statefulset-v1-apps)